# How to assign variable to output of the program in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, terminal, output

Here I have the simple code in which I am trying to store the value of program output to a variable in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for value in {1..10}
do 
    variable=`$value | ./unpackme`
    str="What's my favorite number? Sorry, that's not it!"
    if [[ "$variable" == "$str" ]]
    then
        echo "hello"
    fi
done
```

The output I am getting is as follows:
[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkKm1.png)
Please help me fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `./unpackme` do? Why are you piping the output of `$value` to it?

Comment: unpackme is the program that takes $value as input.

Comment: `$value` will try to run a program called `1`. Do you mean `echo $value` ?

Comment: try with `variable=$(echo $value | ./unpackme)`

Answer (score 0):

You may try :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

str="What's my favorite number? Sorry, that's not it!"
for value in {1..10}; do
    variable=$(./unpackme <<< "$value")
    if [ "$variable" = "$str" ]; then
        echo "hello"
    fi
done
```

Some notes :

- New style `$(command)` is preferred to `` `command` ``.
- `string` in `command <<< string` is what is called a `here string` : `command` standard input is fed with `string` (think of it as : `echo string | command`).
- `[ "$variable" = "$str" ]`: Take care of `[[ "$a" == "$b" ]]`/`[[ "$a" = "$b" ]]`, they will consider the right part of `==`/`=` as a pattern, and may not do what you want.